# ImageView's image is positioned wrong at horizontal orientation

Tags: android, xml, imageview

I have created a android app. Now when the orientation is vertical the image is loaded fine and it is in right way that i want it to like this
[image: vertical Orientation]

`
but when i turn the device horizontally this image is set at the left corner of the imageview 
[image: horizontal Orientation]

the xml for the imageview is as below `

```
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/backdrop"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="matrix"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />
```

`what is the reason causing this behavior ?? is it due to`android:scaleType="matrix"` attribute ?? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Its because of the scaleType of the ImageView, if you want your image to fill the whole container you will need to use a different scaleType like fillXY or CenterCrop.

If you want to master this topic you can check [this](http://etcodehome.blogspot.com/2011/05/android-imageview-scaletype-samples.html) article to compare every scaleType and decide which one fits the best your needs.

Comment: what i really want is that the image's top left corner should coincide with the imageview's top left corner, since the poster is quite larger than the device screeen. Any idea how to do that??

Comment: You can try to fitXY to see how it goes... But I don't really get what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

`Matrix` is probably not what you want to be using. Try either `centerInside` or `centerCrop` and see which you like best. Other variations can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html)

Comment: There are no values such as CENTER_INSIDE or CENTER_CROP

Comment: @Infamous sorry was referring to the programatic way of setting it, have adjusted my post

Comment: do you have any idea how the image's top left corner should coincide with the imageview's top left corner, since the poster is quite larger than the device screeen.when the device is vertical ' android:scaleType="matrix" ' does exactly what i want to do

Comment: I'm fairly certain that `centerCrop` will do exactly what you want for vertical as well. That does not mean it is correct.

And juding by that landscape view the poster is not larger than than landscape screen.

`Matrix` is having 0 effect on the image as you are not setting a matrix